# Django Admin, limit many to many choices with exactly equal forignkeys

Tags: django, django-admin, django-filters

I have three models like that:

Model.1

```
X = CharField(...)
```

Model.2

```
Y = ForeignKey (Model.1...)
```

Model.3

```
¥ = ForeignKey (Model.1...)
Z = ManyToMany(Model.2...)
```

I want to show up model2 objects in many to many select box which have equal foreign key with model 3.

I used (limit chooses)attribute in model3 Z field but its not affect dynamically when I make or edit new model3 object.

How can I make this select box limited to equal forignkeys?

Comment: If `Model3`only contains an FK and M2m, wouldn't it make more sense to define the M2M on `model1`?

Comment: Yes I can do that programmatically but when I use Django admin I can just do that with loading extra JavaScript files in front end. I want to find a way with Django options. Also until I dont create model 3 object, Django admin don't know which is the ForeignKey of that and can't compare that with model2  ForeignKeys